# How to process json file in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have a json data, i want to process that json file as key , value pairs.

Following is the Json data:

```
{
    "profileDetails": {
        "customerCategory": {
            "masterCode": "IND"
        },
        "customerSubCategory": {
            "masterCode": "SALARIED"
        }
    }
}
```

for suppose this stored in a variable `${json_data}`
I want to access the value of the json like,


 if pass the key as `profileDetails.customerCategory.masterCode` then i should get the value as `IND`. 
if pass the key as `profileDetails.customerSubCategory.masterCode` then i should get the value as `SALARIED`.

When i google for the solution , i found one custom code in Git [robotframework-simply-json](https://github.com/abioneperhobby/robotframework-simply-json)

But it serve the purpose if the json data is in linear fashion like key&value pairs already. Like below:

```
{
 "firstName":"Rajani",
 "lastName":"Tumma",
 "age":33,
 "city":"Mysore"

 }
```

Please any one help me, how to process the json test data, if it is not as key value pairs and like the first example.

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: Do you need to iterate over the data as key/value pairs, or simply access the data by supplying a key? Do you _have_ to use dot notation? You can get to the `masterCode` with normal python syntax (eg: ${json_data['profileDetails']['customerCategory']['masterCode']}". Is that good enough?

Comment: This already looks to be in the form of dictionary. So you can even try using "ast.literal_eval" which will allow you to operate on it as a normal dictionary in python.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, i am able to get the value using ${json_data['profileDetails']['customerCategory']['masterCod‌​e']}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to use HttpLibrary?

```
*** Settings ***
Library            HttpLibrary.HTTP

*** Test Cases ***
Parse JSON
    ${json_data}    Set Variable    {"profileDetails":{"customerCategory":{"masterCode":"IND"},"customerSubCategory":{"masterCode":"SALARIED"}}}
    ${json_data}    Parse Json    ${json_data}
    Log    ${json_data["profileDetails"]["customerCategory"]["masterCode"]}
```

Comment: Thanks jan, this is working. I am able to get the json value.

Comment: Nice to hear that.